# Is it sufficient to start Torah reading after only 2.5 verses in a parasha?

Tags: torah-reading, torah-service

In Torah reading, we don't start reading in the middle of a *parasha* when there are fewer than three verses preceding in the *parasha*, and similarly we don't stop reading in the middle of a *parasha* where there are fewer than three verses remaining. See, eg. [Shulchan Aruch OḤ 138:1](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.138.1):

> ‮הקורא בתורה לא ישייר בפרשה פחות מג' פסוקים מפני היוצאים אז מבה"כ שיאמרו העול' אחריו לא יקרא אלא שני פסוקים הנשארים וכן לא יתחיל בה פחות מג' פסוקים מפני הנכנסים אז בב"ה שיאמרו שלא קרא הראשון אלא שני פסוקים: הגה ואין חילוק בין פ' פתוחה לסתומה ...
>
> The one who reads the Torah may not leave over any less than 3 verses in a paragraph because of those who leave the synagogue then and will say that the oleh (i.e. reader) after him will read nothing but the two remaining verses [of the paragraph]. And similarly, one may not begin less than 3 verses into it (i.e. a paragraph) because of those who enter the synagogue then and will say that the first [reader] did not read anything but 2 verses. Gloss: And there is no difference between an open paragraph and a closed paragraph ...

In several places, there is a *parasha* break in the middle of a verse (eg. [Deut 2:8](https://www.sefaria.org/Deuteronomy.2.8)). Do the half-verses count toward the three with regards to this rule? For example, could one stop reading after Deut 2:5, or could one start reading at Deut 2:11?

Comment: Looks like there's probably an answer in Magen Avraham and Kaf HaHayyim there, but I'm not sure whether the "three" the MA mentions is including the half-verse or not.

Comment: This happened to our reading this Shabbat. We found a *p'sul* in the first word of 2:11, and then for the next *oleh*, the decision was made to go back to the beginning of *ḥamishi* (apparently unnecessarily, if you follow Mishna Berura 138:3).

Comment: I'm not sure what you're unsure about the Magen Avraham. He seems to allow ending an aliya within three verses of a break if the break is in the middle of a verse such that no one would think the adjacent aliyah is less than three verses. (Surely others argue)

Comment: @DoubleAA MA writes that it's OK to end at Deut 2:7 (in our example). But then writes ואם טעה וסיים ב' פסוקים לפני הפ' יתחיל אח"כ פסוק למפרע, and I'm not sure what those ב' פסוקים לפני הפ' are referring to: stopping at 2:5 (leaving 2.5 verses in the parasha) or stopping at 2:6 (leaving 1.5 verses)? If the former, he's saying that 2.5 < 3, answering my question; if the latter, then I'm not sure he fully addresses my question.

Comment: As far as I can tell he's just starting a new case that has nothing to do with a parsha in the middle of a pasuk. (Ironic that we are debating if there is a 'break' in the middle of his run on sentence comment.)

Comment: @DoubleAA Ha, ok I didn't think of that read. But then he's not addressing my question at all. He's saying 0.5 might as well be the parasha break for our purposes, but not addressing the case of 2.5 vs 3.

Comment: If you can stop at 0.5 from a break you can stop at 1, 1.5, 2, 2.5 from break too, no? The same logic holds that no one will suspect the adjacent aliyah is less than three verses because everyone knows you don't stop in the middle of a pasuk.

Comment: @DoubleAA Perhaps we don't stop at 1.5 before the break because someone might think the next person will read exactly one verse. But 0.5 is fine, cause no-one's going to read exactly half a verse, so they're clearly reading into the next parasha.

Comment: Why would someone think the next person will read only one verse? Someone could make that mistake at any place. Unless there's a natural stopping point close by such as a parsha break not in the middle of a verse, I don't see the concern. (But that's just me; I also don't understand what gives us the right to make up where we think the concern is justified or not and ignore talmudic rules accordingly, but again that's just me.)

Comment: @DoubleAA Ah, you're suggesting that the MA is arguing that the setuma is irrelevant here, because it's not a stopping point. I see that.